# How to post manytomany field value in Postman for API

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a field which is ManyToMany. I would like to enter the value in POSTMAN for API post operation. But everytime It says:  ***"This field is required."*** even though I provided the value.
[image]

[image]

Models:

```
class Day(models.Model):
   day_name = models.CharField(
      _("Day Name"), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.day_name

class TutorProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    tutor_availablility = models.ManyToManyField(
         Day,blank=True)
```

Serializer:

```
class DaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Day 
    fields = '__all__'
    


class TutorProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(), source='user.username')
    image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')
    
    tutor_availablility = DaySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TutorProfile
        fields = '__all__'
```

Viewsets:

```
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
class TutorprofileViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TutorProfileSerializer
    http_method_names = ["post", "delete", "get"]
    queryset = TutorProfile.objects.all()
```

Comment: plz, add views.py code in question for adding tutor_profile

Comment: Do you mind adding the models, views, and serializer containing the `bio_teacher` as well?

Comment: Probably there’s a problem in your validate method of TutorProfileSerializer, can you pls add it to the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following `models.py` (notice that your current `Day.__str__` can raise an exception if `day_name` does not exist):

```py
class Day(models.Model):
    day_name = models.CharField(_("Day Name"), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.day_name if self.day_name else "Unnamed"


class TutorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tutor_availability = models.ManyToManyField(Day, blank=True)
```

You do not need to explicitly add `tutor_availability` nor `user` as serializer fields:

```py
class DaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Day
        fields = "__all__"


class TutorProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Omitting `image_url` as not reflected in `models.py`
    # image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')
    
    class Meta:
        model = TutorProfile
        fields = "__all__"
```

With this viewset:

```py
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
class TutorProfileViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TutorProfileSerializer
    http_method_names = ["post", "delete", "get"]
    queryset = TutorProfile.objects.all()
```

Then, after creating days with IDs 1 and 2 in admin, by sending the `tutor_availability` field as you are doing it, it should work. Request:

```json
{
    "user": 1,
    "tutor_availability": [1, 2]
}
```

Response:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "user": 1,
    "tutor_availability": [
        1,
        2
    ]
}
```

Notice as well that I've changed `availablility` to `availability` and that it may be unsafe to allow authenticated users to pass the `user` field in the request, you may want to infer that from the user who makes the request.

Comment: I already have that code in model before. When that was not working expectedly than I added that in seralizer. But that is also not working.

Comment: Can you provide your `models.py`?

Comment: Please have a look on the updated question.

Comment: Just updated my response, it's working for me. Maybe there is something relevant in your validations or elsewhere?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UvyP.png It Does not work! It says:  "tutor_availability": [
        "This list may not be empty."
    ]

Answer (score 1):

In your TutorProfileSerializer you are using the DaySerializer for tutor_availablility field so when you do a post request your post action will wait for a list of dict, what you you need to do in first is to delete this line : from your TutorProfileSerializer and it will works.

```
tutor_availablility = DaySerializer(many=True)
```

If you still have the problem then you need to verify the validate method of the TutorProfileSerializer.

And if it works but you want a list of dict(of Day object) for GET request, you need to override the get_serializer_class() of your ViewSet and create two serializers one for post request and a second for get request:

```
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
class TutorprofileViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TutorProfileSerializer
    http_method_names = ["post", "delete", "get"]
    queryset = TutorProfile.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action.method == 'GET':
            return TutorGETProfileSerializer
        return super(TutorprofileViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()
```

and the 2 serializers:

```
class TutorGETProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(), source='user.username')
    image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')
    
    tutor_availablility = DaySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TutorProfile
        fields = '__all__'

class TutorProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TutorProfile
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('user',)
```

Comment: IT does not work! But I Have seen you tried enough so far.